# Subclassing UIControl's endTracking for multitouch

Tags: ios, uikit, multi-touch, uicontrol

I'm creating a custom control* by subclassing UIControl and overriding the following methods:

- `- beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`
- `- continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`
- `- endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`
- `- cancelTrackingWithEvent:`

This control will support multitouch interaction. Specifically, one or two fingers may touch down, drag for some duration, and then touch up, all independently.

My issue comes at the end of these multitouch events, in `endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`. The system calls this method on my control exactly once per multitouch sequence, and it is called on the first touch up that occurs. This means that the second touch, which could still be dragging, will no longer be tracked.

This sequence of actions serves as an example for this phenomenon:

1. Finger **A** touches down. `beginTracking` is called.
2. Finger **A** drags around. `continueTracking` is called repeatedly to update my control.
3. Finger **B** touches down. `beginTracking` is called.
4. Fingers **A** and **B** drag around. `continueTracking` is called repeatedly to update my control.
5. Finger **B** touches up. `endTracking` is called.
6. Finger **A** drags around. No methods are called.
7. Finger **A** touches up. No methods are called.

The issue lies in the final three steps in this sequence. [The documentation for `UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:) says the following of `endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`:

> Sent to the control when the last touch for the given event completely ends, telling it to stop tracking.

Yet it seems to me that after finger **B** touches up in step 5, above, the last touch for the given event has not yet completely ended. That last touch is finger **A**!

---

*A range slider, if you must ask. *But there are already plenty of open source range sliders,* you say. Yes, true, but this one will support multitouch and Auto Layout.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in custom control with multitouch.
Because `UIControl` is subclass of `UIView` that inherits from `UIResponder`, so feel free to use:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

methods.

These methods work fine in `UIControl` subclass.

Comment: This is the approach I'm looking at now. However, this means I'd need to override the `tracking` variable, as well as the `touchInside` variable, since I'm totally short-circuiting `UIControl`'s touch handling. Also, I have to override `hitTest:withEvent:` to make sure that any touches that make it to `touchesBegan:withEvent:` are ones I want to handle, because I can't call `super` at that point.

Comment: Docs says:

Override the beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, and cancelTrackingWithEvent: methods to track touch events occurring in the control. You can use the tracking information to perform additional actions. **Always use these methods to track touch events instead of the methods defined by the UIResponder class.**

Comment: @DamianRzeszot Did you ever find a solution while sticking to the to be overridden methods as stated in the docs ?